# ЧПУ на сайте

Tags: php

Добрый вечер. Помогите разобраться с ЧПУ.
Что здесь не так:

```
RewriteRule ^page&amp;page_id=(\d+) ?view=page&amp;page_id=$1
```

**Обновление**

Допустим, так все отлично работает:

```
RewriteRule ^new$ ?view=new
```

Вы мне покажите, как исправить ту строку в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь не так все. Начиная от того, что get строка, вообще-то должна разбираться в ReqriteCond, а не в RewriteRule, и заканчивая тем, что избавляясь от по-левому записанного (для вывода в html) амперсэнда, вы опять-таки записываете его по-левому.

Опишите задачу подробнее.

**Обновление**

Напишите пример входа и выхода, которые должны обрабатываться.

У меня подозрение, что речь идет о

```
site.ru/page?page_id=23 -> site.ru?view=page&page_id=23
```

тогда

```
RewriteRule ^page&page_id=(\d+) ?view=page&page_id=$1
```

Comment: @knes, спасибо,
 а можно еще амперсэнд заменить?

Comment: Можно, на что?